# html5 - Server side events: Replace line instead of append

Tags: html, server-side

I am aiming at using HTML5 SSE (Server Side Events) to send updates of data from server to the client. Currently the time is appended as an extra line. I am using the [\n\n] in the php-file in order to stop the stream.

**Question:** How can I replace the complete line insted of having it appended? I want the replacement to be in the same place, thus be kept inside the div [result].

I have tried to remove the br-tag at line 17 of the html-file, but it did not remove the "newline".

My html5 file, with js included:

```
  <h1>SSE test</h1>
  <div id="result"></div>

  <script>
      // Create an object
      var source = new EventSource("updater.php");
      // Detect message receipt
      source.onmessage = function(event) {
          // Write the received data to the page
          document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += event.data + "<br>";
      };
  </script>
```

my php file:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

// The server time
  $time = date('r');
  echo "data: The server time is: {$time}\n\n";

flush();
?>
```

Comment: So you don't want to append the result to  #result. Instead just display the latest `event.data`. right?

Comment: @illusion. Exactly, I want to display the latest event.data, without append. Probably easier to think of the example of stock data that is kept in the same div or table cell, but constantly updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `source.onmessage` callback, just change the line to this:

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = event.data + "<br>";
```

The problem is caused by the `+=` operator, which appends the new result to the previous one. Now, with `=` it overwrites the old result, thereby solving the problem.